# lmtree suspect behavior with factors

Tags: r, partitioning, party

I notice a strange behavior of the lmtree function from the partykit package when I use it with factors. If some levels are not included in the dataset (here "c" and "e"), the predictions change randomly ...

I guess this means that lmtree builds the model only with factors existing in the dataset ("a" and "b" in this example) while the predict function takes into account all factors ("a","b","c","e").

So how can I use safely factors with lmtree models ?

```
library(partykit)

df<-data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100),v=sample(c("a","b"),100,replace=T))
df$z<-with(df,ifelse(v=="a",2*y+x,3*x-y))
df$v<-factor(df$v,levels=c("c","e","a","b"))

lmt<-lmtree(z~x+y|v,df)

for (i in 1:10) print(predict(lmt,df,type="node")[1])
```

A similar problem occurs if the order of factor is reversed between the lmtree  function and the predict function (changing from levels=c("a","b") to levels=c("b","a") )

Comment: what package is `lmtree` in? (please include this info in your question ...)

Comment: @BenBolker : from the partykit package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for raising this issue, it's a bug in `partykit` (up to the current version 1.2-2).

The source of the problem is the following: The `lmtree()` takes the `formula` and `data` and builds a `model.frame` from these, setting `drop.unused.levels = TRUE`. Thus, for `v` only levels `"a"` and `"b"` are retained and `"c"` and `"e"` dropped. However, the same is *not* done in `predict.party` where `model.frame` is called without specifying `drop.unused.levels` and thus using the default `FALSE`. And then there is a mismatch between the factor levels, resulting in random assignments.

I will coordinate a fixed version with Torsten! The same problem seems to lurk in other places so we need to do some more checking first.

In the meantime the best way to avoid this is to drop the unused levels before calling `lmtree` (or other functions in `partykit` which seem to have the same problem).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will wait for the updated version !